# Android app that looks like Facebook UI

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface

I want to develop a UI and display it the save way Facebook app does. Is there any open source code available can show me how to display facebook feeds/posts exactly how facebook does?

Here is a sample image (I cannot link image as I do not have 10 reputtion :( ) (http://www.smartkeitai.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/facebook-android-app-1-470x800.jpg?00d448). To be specific I want to display feed like it is displayed for David and SAnder

Thanks,

Comment: Not everybody in the world uses Facebook, let alone the Facebook Android app. You may be better served by taking some screenshots, uploading them somewhere, linking to them in your question, and explaining **precisely** what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I thought person who wil knew the answer to my question will know exactly how Facebook app works or coded so need to be that explanatory. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any open source code available can show me how to display facebook feeds/posts exactly how facebook does?

You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see specifically what they do. However, based on your screenshot, that looks to be a set of `TextView` and `ImageView` widgets, in some sort of container(s) (could be just about anything: `RelativeLayout`, `GridLayout`, nested `LinearLayout`s, `TableLayout`, etc.). Each of those is probably a row in a `ListView`. IOW, there is nothing special here that would somehow require a third-party library.

Comment: I realize that. I was looking for a code that I can consume in my app to produce such an output instead of hand coding each bits piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can make PhoneGap application and extract Facebook CSS from Facebook mobile site that is used in some mobile apps.

The version of Facebook you showed is native and it is just step by step customization to get exact looks.

I am not sure why you wish to replicate Facebook interface. I hope it is legal.

Android app written in Java is very easy to de-compile, modify and compile again.

So if it is legal in your country to decompile Facebook app then you may get its source code in 5-20 minutes including resources, etc

Comment: Ha ha ha. seriously like the hacking approach just not into it. :) but I appreciate your help. There are like 100s of apps with exactly same look and feel like facebook so I guess nothing copyrighted with that.

Comment: Yes. I have not understood you. I thought you wish to have exact look. Otherwise you create list item control and put this controls in a list. Google "android listview with custom items"